# Having trouble finding graphics driver - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 18.04, steam

I am new to linux and installed Ubuntu 18.04. I am having trouble installing graphics drivers. I have rebooted a fresh install like 10 or so times yesterday, installed steam, it boots into one game but the graphic are real sticky and my one game wont even boot up at all. I used YouTube tutorials, used software and updates to find proprietary drivers -those don't work, used fresh install xorg drivers - those don't work, and then a few tutorials of different version of developed drivers, and ran into some errors that forced me to reboot because it wouldn't even boot into desktop, or had on install freeze , and another install just not finish but desktop didnt freeze.

I am new to linux and very vulnerable because of my money situation , medications im tapering off, I have some anger issues, mental health issues, everything you name it. I can't even post on reddit because my karma is so bad, but i just posted some music i made on a trendy artist post when his new album came out in the music reddit. never said anything negative.

so any help would much be appreciated, thanks

here is a snap of my specs - i have i7 core, intel nvidia geforce 630, (kaby lake gt2) 7.7 gb memory, and 200gb solid state drive:

[![][1]][1]

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 118a
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: We don't want a screenshot of your system information specs, we want you to execute the command that Pilot6 asked you to execute, then we want you to copy/paste the output from terminal into your question as an edit.  The screenshot of the 'specs' of your computer don't help us here.

Comment: done--------------------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

Disable Secure Boot in BIOS and run

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390
```

Then reboot.

You can also use a GUI tool "Software & Updates" -> Additional Drivers.

Comment: sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
sudo apt install nvidia-390
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.       when I got these errors I just did a fresh install and it helped.... how do i correct the dpkg error?

Comment: tried to purge and got the same error

Comment: Why not run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`? It means that you interrupted some install. The message is clear enough.